# Memory Leak? Or bug in instruments?

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory-management, memory-leaks, instruments

I'm sure it's a memory leak, and I'm certainly no expert in memory allocation, but instruments says I have a memory leak of zero bytes...[image]

Can someone explain what exactly that means?

Comment: Have you tried moving the top arrow where the red area is?

Comment: I doubt it is a bug, you should have a call stack in instruments in the lower panel that tells you what line of code the leak is being reported for. Find that out and update your question with the code in question and we can help you fix the leak.

Answer (score 0):

The leaked object (including the responsible party that initiates it) should appear in the lower half part of the Instruments window, once you have selected the "Leaks Discovered".

Doing an "Analyze" (Command + I) in XCode will also show possible memory leaks in your code.